# How do I get exit code of script run with mintty.exe?

Tags: windows, cygwin, exit-code, errorlevel, mintty

In Windows, I'm excecuting a bash script using Cygwin64 and mintty.exe, this way:

`mintty.exe -e C:\some_path\some_bash_script.sh`

I need to capture the script's errors but %ERRORLOVEL% is always 0, even when the script fails.

How can I get the exit code of the bash script, when executed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mintty does not return any error code, what you can do is :

```
mintty.exe -e bash -c "C:\some_path\some_bash_script.sh; echo $? > /c/temp/return-code"
```

and test the content of C:\temp\return-code

Comment: Thanks, I ended doing someting like this: ```mintty.exe -w hide -e bash -c 'script.sh 1^>stdout.txt 2^>stderr.txt' ```

Comment: Glad it helped. Have you tried double quotes `"` so you don't have to escape `>` using `1^` ?

Comment: The thing is I'm executing this from inside python, so I'm already using single and double quotes for the whole sentence. So, I'm fine with the escape chars.

Comment: But you where right: I've inverted single and double quotes and then were able to get rid of the escape chars. Thanks!